# NestJS How to dynamically override an injected service of an imported module

Tags: dependency-injection, nestjs

I have a library module named `KafkaModule` that exports a `KafkaService`. `KafkaService` uses an other service called `EventStoreService` that implements the interface `EventStore`.

```
import { DynamicModule, Module, Type } from '@nestjs/common';
import { KafkaConfig } from 'kafkajs';
import { KafkaService } from './kafka.service';
import { EventStoreService } from './default-event-store/event-store.service';
import { MongooseModule, MongooseModuleOptions } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { AppEvent, AppEventSchema } from './default-event-store/schema';

export interface EventPublisherConfig {
  kafkaConfig: KafkaConfig;
  topic: string;
  uri: string;
  options?: MongooseModuleOptions;
}

@Module({})
export class KafkaModule {
  static async register(config: EventPublisherConfig): Promise<DynamicModule> {
    const { kafkaConfig, topic, uri, options } = config;
    return {
      imports: [
        MongooseModule.forRoot(uri, options),
        MongooseModule.forFeature([
          { name: AppEvent.name, schema: AppEventSchema },
        ]),
      ],
      global: true,
      module: KafkaModule,
      providers: [
        EventStoreService,
        KafkaService,
        {
          provide: 'EVENT_STORE',
          useExisting: EventStoreService,
        },
        {
          provide: 'KAFKA_CONFIG',
          useValue: kafkaConfig,
        },
        {
          provide: 'TOPIC',
          useValue: topic,
        },
      ],
      exports: [EventStoreService, KafkaService],
    };
  }
}
```

`KafkaService` injects the `EventStoreService` like this:

```
@Inject('EVENT_STORE') eventStore: EventStore
```

When I inject KafkaModule in AModule, how can I override the default EventStoreService ? I tried this in AModule:

```
provider: [
   {
      provide: 'EVENT_STORE',
      useClase: OverridedEventStoreFromAModuleService
   }
]
```

But it didn't work..